# avoid Doctrine DBAL query builder select statement to transform camelcase aliase names to lowercase

Tags: php, doctrine-query

I'm using doctrine DBAL in custom PHP application and in my case when I use query builder `select` statement for example like:

```
->select(
         'roles.id as roleId',
                'roles.slug as roleSlug',
                'roles.name as roleName',)
```

in the result array, keys are like `roleslug`, `rolename`. Do I need to add some configuration to avoid lowering the aliases by doctrine? I found nothing in the doctrine documentation related to that

Answer (score 2):

This is related to PostgreSQL. Just wrap your select to doublequotes likes this:

```
->select(
         'roles.id as "roleId"',
                'roles.slug as "roleSlug"',
                'roles.name as "roleName"',)
```